# Is there a way to boot a computer with veracrypt on it

Tags: veracrypt

Recently i found a old laptop which had veracrypt on it i tried a few passwords but nothing worked is there a way to fix the laptop so that it can normally like is there a way to install windows again and is it still possible for me to get access to the data on the machine with veracrypt still on it?

Comment: Sure; Boot into WinPE and delete all the partitions on the disk. Without the password you will be unable to access the data on the drive

Comment: If there were backdoors or work arounds to encryption, encryption would be pointless. The reason encryption works is because there are not backdoors or work arounds. So, the only way through Veracrypt is using the correct password. Without that there is no access to the encrypted data. Without access to the encrypted data you just need to do a normal "clean" OS install, which is very well documented all over the internet, including on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Booting a computer with Veracrypt, accessing data in the encrypted partition and installing Windows (or any other OS for that matter) are very different and independent situations, you mustn't confuse them...

- Booting a computer with the OS or OSes encrypted by Veracrypt requires the Veracrypt's password;
- Accessing user's data also requires the OS user's password in order to login after decryption with the aforementioned Veracrypt's password.

You don't have any so you must assume the loss and move on. If encryption could be easily thwarted wouldn't be much point i using it, don't you think?

Now, nothing of the above prevents you to install a new OS from scratch. Simply remove all partitions and let the installer go from there. This is applicable to Windows or any mainstream Linux distro.

Comment: So ur telling there is no way to decrypt the computer to access its old data and how do i install a new os frm scratch if i cannot access the windows that veracrypt is preventing me frm accessing btw i am new to this os and encryption thing

Comment: You DON'T need access to anything in the drive to install a new OS. How to do it has been explained in the question and it should be easy to understand, it's no different than installing any OS in a previously used drive and deleting everything. And yes, absolutely you CAN'T access anything already there if you don't have the passwords.

Comment: And now you have one answer plus two comments saying basically the same... And to be clear, when installing any OS you'll be booting from external installation/*live media (e.g. USB stick), NOT from the internal drive therefore Veracrypt isn't triggered.

Comment: Is it possible to remove the partition that the veracrypt is using to then install a new os

Comment: *Is it possible to remove the partition that the veracrypt is using to then install a new os* Exactly what the answer and the comments reiterated.